# Reversing branch differences (Git)

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Suppose the branch `dev` was forked from `master`, edited and then merged back into branch `master`.

Now I need to get the latest snapshot of the repo of `master` minus changes from `dev`. How?

Comment: You can checkout the revision just before the merge and make a new branch from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> master minus changes from dev

This can mean different things.

Here are two possibilities

### Master without a special commit

You could checkout current master, create a feature branch and revert the commit from dev.

### Just the difference

You could just compare the branches with git diff.

### Master from the moment before `dev` was merged in

`git checkout master commit_before_the_merge_commit`.

You can find `commit_before_the_merge_commit` with `git log`.